# Android Emulator Screen scaling issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, dpi

Ever since I installed KDE Neon as my linux distro, I've been having some problems with the Android Emulator. For some reason, it refuses to populate the entire android screen. Weird thing is, the touch listeners are on the correct spot on the screen, but the displayed screen is only a fourth of the device.

Could anyone help me out?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with plasma scale display. In display settings set it to 1, I also set force font dpi in font setting to 144 in my case, it does almost same that scale display does.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it adding this line inside the `studio.sh` file:

> QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1

Be aware that when Android Studio will update, you will have to add it again.

Working in KDE Neon with Plasma 5.13